# Bigquery CASE SENSITIVE query with LIMIT clause is not working?

Tags: google-bigquery, limit, case-sensitive

When making a Bigquery query like for example:

```
Select Campaign FROM TABLE WHERE Campaign CONTAINS 'buy' GROUP BY Campaign IGNORE CASE LIMIT 100
```

The IGNORE CASE clause is not working when used with LIMIT clause.

Some time ago it did work. 
Is this a Bigquery fault or something changed?

Thanks a lot
Ramiro

Comment: does not look like a question. you should submit issue  here - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things here:

- Legacy SQL expects `IGNORE CASE` to appear at the end of the query, so you need to use `LIMIT 100 IGNORE CASE` instead of `IGNORE CASE LIMIT 100`
- The BigQuery team advises using [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/) instead of legacy SQL if you're working on new queries, since it tends to have better error messages, better performance, etc. and it's where we're focusing our efforts going forward. You may also be interested in the [migration guide](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql).

If you want to use standard SQL for your query, you could do:

```
Select LOWER(Campaign) AS Campaign
FROM TABLE
WHERE LOWER(Campaign) LIKE '%buy%'
GROUP BY LOWER(Campaign)
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: `LIMIT 100 IGNORE CASE` does not work either and based on `Some time ago it did work` it is not new query o) but obviously you are right about migrating to Standard SQL